# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method ..., and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, linq

My function is as on lambda expression

```
public IList<ent_Message> messageDetailsArray(decimal from,decimal to)
        {
            owncibai_ExamEntities db = new owncibai_ExamEntities();
            var details = db.Messages.OrderBy(or=>or.mDate).Where(wh => (wh.userNumber==from && wh.messageTo==to) || (wh.messageTo==from && wh.userNumber==to)).Select(a => new ent_Message
            {
                isRead = a.isRead,
                mDate = a.mDate,
                Message1 = a.Message1,
                messID = a.messID,
                userNumber = a.userNumber,
                messageTo=a.messageTo,
                Name=a.User.First_Name+" "+a.User.Last_Name,
                photo = (db.MessagePhotoes.Where(ph => ph.messID == a.messID).Select(b => new ent_MessagePhoto
                {
                    msgPhoto=b.msgPhoto,
                    srl=b.srl
                })).ToList()
            }).ToList();
            var update = db.Messages.Where(wh => wh.messageTo == from).ToList();
            update.ForEach(a => a.isRead = true);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return details;
        }
```

It works fine when I remove Photo parameter from list. While I add photo it is giving following error.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Entities.ent_MessagePhoto] ToList[ent_MessagePhoto](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Entities.ent_MessagePhoto])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Entity class is as follows

```
public class ent_Message{
     public decimal messID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> userNumber { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> messageTo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> mDate { get; set; }
        public string ip { get; set; }
        public string Message1 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> isRead { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> parentID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IList<ent_MessagePhoto> photo { get; set; }
}
```

I am totally confused where I am wrong in photo...

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a shot in the very dark but can you try adding a `.ToList()` before the `.Select(a => new ent_Message` in the `var details = ` line?

Comment: I think the error is due to the ToList() specified while getting the photos. The post here discusses something similar i.e. you cannot call ToList inside an linq-to-entities query. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213744/linq-querying-list-in-list

Comment: This was an exception in older EF versions. Please always tell which version you use.

Answer (score 2):

This bit:

```
photo = (db.MessagePhotoes.Where(ph => ph.messID == a.messID).Select(b => new ent_MessagePhoto
    {
        msgPhoto=b.msgPhoto,
        srl=b.srl
    })).ToList() //<-right here
```

appears inside your outer `Select` clause. When the IQueryProvider tries to convert your outer `Select` statement to valid SQL, it will see an inner `Select`, which of course can be converted to SQL, but then it will hit the `ToList()` call and fail, because there is no equivalent in SQL.

If you want to perform some operations in your `Select` projection that can't be done in SQL, they need to be done against the query result set in-memory on the .NET application side. One common way to do this is to put a `ToList()` *before* your select statement - this will be interpreted as "send the Where and OrderBy parts to SQL, bring the full result set back into a List, *then* perform the Select projection".

Comment: How should this be done without using the ToList() ?

Answer (score 0):

ent_MessagePhoto must be in the class definition

```
public class ent_Message<ent_MessagePhoto>
    {
        public decimal messID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> userNumber { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> messageTo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> mDate { get; set; }
        public string ip { get; set; }
        public string Message1 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> isRead { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> parentID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IList<ent_MessagePhoto> photo { get; set; }
    }​
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestion I resolved this issue. Issue was version only. I was using 5.x and updated to 6.x and working fine.